# Computing the restriction $(\Lambda^2T_{\mathbb{P}^n})_{|L}$ for line in $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, projective-space

From the Euler sequence

$$0\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\to V\otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)\to T_{\mathbb{P}^n}\to0$$

it is easy to deduce that $T_{\mathbb{P}^n|L}=\mathcal{O}_L(2)\oplus\mathcal{O}_L(1)^{\oplus(n-1)}$ for any line $L\subset\mathbb{P}^n$.

Now for any line $L\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ I want to compute $(\Lambda^2T_{\mathbb{P}^n})_{|L}$. 
For convenience suppose that $L=\{z_2=z_3=...=z_n=0\}$.

It seems true that after taking the second exterior power of the Euler sequence we obtain

$$0\to T_{\mathbb{P}^n}\to \Lambda^2V\otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(2)\to \Lambda^2T_{\mathbb{P}^n}\to0,$$
thus after the restriction to $L$ we obtain the exact sequence
$$0\to\mathcal{O}_L(2)\oplus\mathcal{O}_L(1)^{\oplus(n-1)}\to \Lambda^2V\otimes\mathcal{O}_{L}(2)\to(\Lambda^2T_{\mathbb{P}^n})_{|L}\to0.$$

The problem is that I don't understand much what is the first map in this exact sequence so I can't figure out what is the cokernel.

Comment: You can use that exterior powers commute with pullbacks.

Comment: Surely. The answer is just $\mathcal{O}_L(2)^{\oplus3}\oplus\mathcal{O}_L(3)^{\oplus3}$.

Comment: Yes, if $n=4$. For any $n$ it is $\mathcal{O}_L(2)^{\oplus \binom{n-1}{2}}\oplus \mathcal{O}_L(3)^{\oplus (n-1)}$.